# Having trouble preventing the duplication of CSS code

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, css-animations

I have the following snippet:

```js
// Second Banner
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  let executionFlag = true;
  const toastSecond = document.getElementById("toastSecond");

  const toastCloseSecond = document.getElementById("toastCloseSecond");



  window.onscroll = function(b) {
    const percentToScroll = 0.9; //0.9 of the page
    if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight * percentToScroll && executionFlag) {


      toastSecond.classList.add("open1");
      executionFlag = false;
    }
  };

  toastCloseSecond.addEventListener("click", function() {
    toastSecond.classList.remove("open1");
  });

})

// First Banner
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  (function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      var banner;
      banner = document.querySelector('.exponea-banner');
      banner.classList.add('exponea-in');
      return banner.querySelector('.exponea-close').addEventListener('click', function() {
        return banner.classList.remove('exponea-in');
      });
    });

  }).call(this);
});
```

````css
.exponea-banner {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #2e364d;
  color: #ebeef7;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 30px rgba(116, 119, 176, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  display: none;
}

.exponea-banner.exponea-in {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.exponea-banner .exponea-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.exponea-banner .exponea-label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.exponea-banner .exponea-text {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.exponea-banner .exponea-count {
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-weight: 300;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.exponea-banner .exponea-label {
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.exponea-banner,
.exponea-close,
.exponea-text,
.exponea-label,
.exponea-label {
  z-index: 999;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}


/* SecondBanner */

.exponea-banner1 {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #2e364d;
  color: #ebeef7;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999999999;
}

.open1 {
  display: block;
}

.exponea-banner1 .exponea-close1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.exponea-banner1 .exponea-label1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.exponea-banner1 .exponea-text1 {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.exponea-banner1 .exponea-count1 {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.exponea-banner1 .exponea-label1 {
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

```
````

```html
<!-- First banner -->
<div class="exponea-banner open">
  <div class="exponea-close">
    &times;
  </div>
  <div class="exponea-text">
    Ex 1
  </div>
  <div class="exponea-label">
    - user
  </div>
</div>

<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>

<!-- Second Banner -->
<div class="exponea-banner1" id="toastSecond">
  <div class="exponea-close1" id="toastCloseSecond">&times;</div>
  <div class="exponea-text1"> Ex 2
  </div>
  <div class="exponea-count"> some text</div>
  <div class="exponea-label1">user</div>
</div>
```

This basically produces two exact same banners. The first banner is displayed as soon as the page loads, and the second banner loads at `0.9` of the page as stated in the JS.

Since both banners are the exact same, is there a way to shorten the CSS for it so that the only difference between the two banners is how they behave such as the functionality where one is displayed at the start and the other is 0.9 of the page?

I basically want to avoid duplicating the CSS

I tried making it common but then it messes up the JS file, and then the second banner is not even loading on screen.

Comment: The code as posted does not change the visual as you describe once it runs

Comment: Sorry, just edited to represent the visual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave both of the banners the same classes, since both have the same styling properties and values, and I gave an extra `attribute` which is `data-banner`, and the values are unique, and that's how we can select them in `JS`.

Now, both of the banners have two things in common:
1- They get activate 
2- They deactivated by clicking the close button

The only difference is the condition of when it's going to be activated.

So I created two functions, one for activating and one for closing. 
`activeBanner` and `closeBanner`, both takes 3 arguments (banner element, active class, close element)

And two more functions to handle each banner. 
`bannerOneHandler` will active the banner immediately.
`bannerTwoHandler` will active the banner based on scrolling.

**Note:** 
I called both of the functions on the bottom of the `script` file. But you can add an event for the document on DOMContentLoaded and move them to the event function.

```js
// Get the banners
var banner1 = document.querySelector('[data-banner="first"]');
var banner2 = document.querySelector('[data-banner="second"]');


const closeBanner = (banner, activeClass, closeEl) => {
  // Get "close" element and add the event to remove active class 
  let close = banner.querySelector(`.${closeEl}`)
  close.addEventListener('click', () => {
     banner.classList.remove(activeClass);
  });
}

const activeBanner = (banner, activeClass, closeEl) => {
   // Active the banner and call the closeBanner function
   banner.classList.add(activeClass);
   closeBanner(banner, activeClass, closeEl)
}


// Banner one handler
const bannerOneHandler = (banner) => {
  activeBanner(banner, 'open', 'exponea-close');
};
// Banner two handler
const bannerTwoHandler = (banner) => {
  let executionFlag = true;
  const percentToScroll = 0.9;
  
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    let windowHeightScroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollY;
    let targetScroll = document.body.offsetHeight * percentToScroll

    if (windowHeightScroll >= targetScroll && executionFlag) {
      executionFlag = false;
      activeBanner(banner, 'open', 'exponea-close');
    }
  });
};


// Call the functions
bannerOneHandler(banner1)
bannerTwoHandler(banner2)
```

```css
.exponea-banner {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #2e364d;
  color: #ebeef7;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 30px rgba(116, 119, 176, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.exponea-banner .exponea-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.exponea-banner .exponea-label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.exponea-banner .exponea-text {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.exponea-banner .exponea-count {
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-weight: 300;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.exponea-banner .exponea-label {
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.exponea-banner,
.exponea-close,
.exponea-text,
.exponea-label,
.exponea-label {
  z-index: 999;
}

.open {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!-- First banner -->
<div class="exponea-banner" data-banner="first">
  <div class="exponea-close">
    &times;
  </div>
  <div class="exponea-text">
    Hi There! Thanks For Stumbling Upon My Website!
  </div>
  <div class="exponea-label">
    - Hussain Omer
  </div>
</div>

<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>

<!-- Second Banner -->
<div class="exponea-banner" data-banner="second">
  <div class="exponea-close">&times;</div>
  <div class="exponea-text"> Thanks For Visiting!
  </div>
  <div class="exponea-count"> Feel Free To Contact Me!</div>
  <div class="exponea-label">- Hussain Omer</div>
</div>
```